# Planck's assumption on blackbody radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I have just started basic quantum mechanics and have come across this expression for energy density of blackbody radiations; Planck's formulation.
$$ u_{\nu} \ d\nu = g(\nu) \ \langle E \rangle \ d\nu
$$

The textbook says that:

> To model the absorption and emission of electromagnetic radiation by these
> oscillators, he argued that the spectral energy density of the black body
> radiation over a range of frequency dv is nothing but the product of the number
> of oscillators having a frequency between v and v + dv , g(v) and the average
> energy ⟨E⟩, of an oscillator having a frequency v :

What I don't understand is: if u(v) is the energy density (per unit v), isn't **$u(\nu)\ d\nu$** the total energy instead of energy density?
And one more question; if $g(\nu)$ is the number of oscillators having frequency in the range $d\nu$, and $⟨E⟩$ is the average energy; then isn't their product the total energy instead of being the energy density, and if that is supposed to be so then why do we have a $d\nu$ part on the right side of equation also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(\nu)$ would be the number density of oscillators per unit frequency at a frequency $\nu$.

$u(\nu)\ d\nu$ would be the energy density in a frequency band $d\nu$ at a frequency $\nu$.

The $d\nu$ is written on both sides of the equation since otherwise you are saying $0 = 0$, because no oscillators have a frequency of *exactly* $\nu$.